# Pinax how to add buttons to navigation bar ,site_base.html?

Tags: django, pinax

I`m using django and pinax the first .I started a new pinax project but found there was no navigation bar on the homepage.Then I add django-user-accounts to the project ,but don`t know how to add "logout" and "settings" buttons to the homepage.Shall I modify the site_base.html ,and how?

This is site_base.html

```
{% extends "theme_base.html" %}

{% load staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}

{# remove to bring back topbar #}
{% block topbar_base %}{% endblock %}

{% block style_base %}
    <link href="{% static "pinax/css/theme.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static "css/site.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
    {% block extra_style %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_head_base %}
{% block extra_head %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
    {% include "_footer.html" %}
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_body_base %}
    {% block extra_body %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}

{% block script_base %}
    <script src="{% block jquery_src %}{% static "pinax/js/jquery.js" %}{% endblock %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "js/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static "pinax/js/theme.js" %}"></script>
    {% block extra_script %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It doesn't work if you remove the line: {# remove to bring back topbar #}?

And look at https://github.com/pinax/pinax-project-account/blob/master/project_name/templates/_account_bar.html

it seems that it has "logout" option.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this

```
{# remove to bring back topbar #}
{% block topbar_base %}{% endblock %}
```

And your navbar will return. Now you add a navbar to it too.